# How do I find and Replace in anouther excel document

Tags: excel, vba

I am tring to create a macro (in Excel) to open another excel worksheet, do a find-replace, then save it.

I have already achieved this with a word document like this:

```
...
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
If wrdApp Is Nothing Then Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(TemplateFilePath)
...

Call WordReplace(wrdDoc,"a","b")

....

Private Sub WordReplace(wrdDoc As Word.Document, sFind As String, sReplace As String)
  With wrdDoc.Content.Find
    .Text = sFind
    .Replacement.Text = sReplace
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End Sub
```

I have crudely tried to replace the word "Word" with "Excel" in the above code to no avail.

Can somone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: have a look here: http://www.ozgrid.com/ The site is a bit disorganized, but the Excel info is extensive.

Comment: Just as a matter of curiosity, why did you not record an Excel macro?

Comment: @Remou, I have found recoreded macros a bit iffy in the past, it might have worked...

Comment: That may be true, but it is generally a much better guide than using a macro from a different application. You may have to tidy the macro, but at least you will get the required input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
Sub a()

Dim excDoc As Workbook
....

Set excDoc = Workbooks.Open("c:\mata.xls")
Call WordReplace(excDoc, "a", "b")
....
End Sub

Private Sub WordReplace(excDoc As Variant, sFind As String, sReplace As String)

Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In excDoc.Worksheets
  With sht
       .Cells.Replace What:=sFind, Replacement:=sReplace, LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great!  Slight modification: `excApp` is no longer needed, perhaps someone can edit this?